# Como extraer solo algunas columnas de un xlsx . Las que no quiero extraer contienen errores que estropean todo el dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Navegando en preguntas similares he visto una persona que proponía:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

csv = StringIO('''\
colA;candidate_name;colF;disbursement_amount;colG;disbursement_date
1;dad;aaa;145;46;10/01/2018
2;fff;yff;16;145;11/01/2018
3;hrf;rrr;96;62;12/01/2018
''')

df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=';', usecols=("candidate_name",
                                        "disbursement_amount",
                                        "disbursement_date"))
```

Pero el al final importa todas las columnas del csv.
En cuanto hago:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=';', usecols=("candidate_name",
                                        "disbursement_amount")
```

Obtengo el error:

> EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

¿No hay manera de leer solo unas determinadas columnas del csv/xlsx?

Comment: No he podido replicar tu error. Sería bueno que agregues más detalles

Comment: from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

csv = StringIO('''\
colA;candidate_name;colF;disbursement_amount;colG;disbursement_date
1;dad;aaa;145;46;10/01/2018
2;fff;yff;16;145;11/01/2018
3;hrf;rrr;96;62;12/01/2018
''')

df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=';', usecols=("candidate_name",
                                        "disbursement_amount"))

Answer (score 0):

#### opcion1

```py
import numpy as np 

csv =np.loadtxt(r'filepath\name.csv',dtype=str,delimiter=';',usecols=(>Indica las columnas que quieres usar<))

csv=pd.DataFrame(csv) #para convertirlo a dataframe
```

#### opcion 2

Una vez cargado el csv tal y como lo cargas.

```py
df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=';')

df=df[['Indica las columnas con las que te quieres quedar']]
```

No se si es lo que buscas pero espero servirte de ayuda